# WOS2 Identity Server v5.4.0 unable to add regexp Callback Url in the Service Provider configuration

Tags: wso2, identity, openid-connect, callbackurl, wso2-identity-server

Having WSO2 Identity Server v5.4.0 and following the documentation from this link [Configuring OAuth2-OpenID Connect Single-Sign-On](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS540/Configuring+OAuth2-OpenID+Connect+Single-Sign-On), I am unable to set Callback Url using **regexp=** for multiple URLs, even setting the example from the documentation:

> regexp=(https://myapp.com/callback|https://testapp:8000/callback)

[image]

I'm getting the error:

"Please enter valid URI for Callback URL":

[image: Error]

NOTE: with single URL (like "https://myapp.com/callback" I have no problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be due to https://wso2.org/jira/browse/IDENTITY-7149 and the fix is available in the latest 5.4.0 update ([update 6](https://github.com/wso2/product-is/releases/tag/v5.4.0-update6)) or the latest GA version [IS 5.4.1](https://wso2.com/identity-and-access-management#download). My recommendation is to use IS 5.4.1 as it is the latest available GA.

Comment: Updated to WSO2 IS v5.4.1 and problem is fixed. Thanks.